# if $f(x)f(y) = y^h f(x/2) + x^k f(y/2)$ for all positive reals $x,y$, then $f$ must be identically zero

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, functional-equations

> Prove that if $h\neq k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is a real-valued function so that $f(x)f(y) = y^h f(x/2) + x^k f(y/2)$ for all positive reals $x,y$, then $f$ must be identically zero.

If one equates $f(y)f(x) = f(x)f(y)$ (using the original functional equation), one gets that for $x\neq 1, f(x/2) = A((2x)^h - (2x)^k)$ for some constant $A$. If one assumes that the coefficients of terms with equal exponents must match, then we get $A=0$ (in more detail, we equate $A^2((2x)^h - (2x)^k)((2y)^h - (2x)^k) = (x^h - x^k) A y^h + x^k A (y^h - y^k).$ But since $h$ and $k$ are real, it's not clear that equating coefficients on both sides is even valid. For polynomials, of course it would be valid since nonconstant polynomials only have finitely many roots.

I'm not sure if the set $\{x^i : i \in \mathbb{R}\}$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.
If the given set is in fact linearly independent, then for any $k\ge 1$ and constants $c_1,\cdots, c_k\in \mathbb{R}$, if $c_1 x^{i_1} + c_2 x^{i_2}+\cdots + c_k x^{i_k} = 0$ (i.e. it's the zero function) then $c_1=c_2=\cdots = c_k = 0.$

Comment: I think your approach is reasonable.  You can verify independence of the functions $x^k$ and $x^h$ by employing Wronskian test.

Comment: If $i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k$ and $c_k>0$, then choosing $x > \max_{j<k} \left(\frac{|c_j|}{k c_k}\right)^{1/(i_k-i_j)}$ gives $\sum c_j x^{i_j} > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial Solution:

First, note that
$$f(0)^2 = 0^hf(0) + 0^kf(0) = 0.$$

The remainder of this answer **assumes** that $f(1) = 0$.
Now with $x = y = 1$,
$$0 = f(1/2)+f(1/2) \implies f(1/2) = 0.$$

Finally, for arbitary $x$ (set $y = 1$),
$$0 = f(2x)f(1) = f(x)+(2x)^kf(1/2) = f(x).$$
Therefore,
$$f(x) =0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+.$$

Comment: What if $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ doesn't exist? It's not obvious if we can always claim $f(1)=0$

Comment: @aschepler, you have a good point.  I neglected to consider that $h,k$ might be negative.  So, in my answer I just assumed that $f$ would be bounded near zero.